# Getting Registry Key of all machines in the domain

Tags: powershell

sorry if it's a silly question. I'm trying to get the "EnableDCOM" Registry Key of all the machines on the domain and disable them. I'm kinda stuck with getting the status of the registry key.

Get-Adcomputer -Filter * | Get-itemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\OLE -name "EnableDCOM"

Here is the error:

Get-ItemProperty : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName
At line:1 char:28

- ... -filter * | Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\OLE -name ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (CN=DAYGROUP-PCI...=daygroup,DC=ca:PSObject) [Get-ItemProperty], ParameterB
    indingArgumentTransformationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyComman
    d

After trying to use the domain admin credential:

The provider does not support the use of credentials. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.
At line:1 char:1

- get-adcomputer -filter * | Get-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Micr ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
  ```

Comment: You can't just chain commands and expect it to do what you're thinking. I see the call to get the property just not to set it. A solution would be to use a loop to iterate through each computer returned from `Get-ADComputer`, passing them over to `Invoke-Command` and having your `Get/Set-ItemProperty` call inside the scriptblock.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: To add to Abraham's comment: Assuming all computers are set up for PowerShell remoting: `Invoke-Command -Computer (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name { Get-itemProperty -path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\OLE -name "EnableDCOM" }`

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you. Don`t forget to specify different credential if needed.

```
$ADComputers = ( Get-ADComputer -Filter * ).Name 
$ResultArray = @()
foreach ( $Computer in $ADComputers ){
    #Maybe you need specify different credential  -Credential $cred     
    $Value = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
        $Value = Get-ItemPropertyValue -path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\OLE' -name 'EnableDCOM'
        return $Value
    }
    
    $PSO = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Computer = $Computer
        Value    = $Value
    }

    $ResultArray += $PSO
}

$ResultArray
```